# How to change the quality of an upload using Paperclip?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, upload, imagemagick, paperclip, image-resizing

I've looked everywhere I cannot understand how to CHANGE the quality of the **ORIGINAL** using paperclip.

On every thread everyone shows how to do that with the generated thumbnail for instance:

```
 has_attached_file :img, styles: { thumb: "400x400#" }, convert_options: { thumb: '-quality 60 -strip'}
```

That works great. However I would like to do this post-processing on the original upload. I've tried

```
 has_attached_file :img, styles: { thumb: "400x400#" }, convert_options: { thumb: '-quality 60 -strip', original: '-quality -50 -strip'}
```

But this doesn't work, my original photo is still huge.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the answer below work for you?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't :)

see my comment below

Answer (score 1):

To change the quality of a photo uploaded try code below:

```
has_attached_file :img, 
              :styles          => { :thumb => '400x400#' },
              :convert_options => { :thumb => '-quality 80' }
```

Another thing you can do is to create multiple times the same image with variations of size, so then you call the size of the image you want. See steps below:

1. Create folders in `app/assets/images` with the names specifying the qualities desired. For example you can have: `app/assets/images/large`, `app/assets/images/medium`, `app/assets/images/thumb` (you already have this one) and many others as you want.
2. In the model of the object that has attachment do the following:

   ```
   has_attached_file :photo,
     styles: { original: "4000x4000>", large:"2000x2000>" ,medium:  "800x800>" ,thumb: "400x400>" },
     default_url: ":style/missing.png"
   ```
3. Then in your view you can do:

   ```
   <%= image_tag(yourObjectWithImgHere.img.url(:thumb) %>
   <%= image_tag(yourObjectWithImgHere.img.url(:medium) %>
   ```

You can go further on convert options or resizing images by reading [this tutorial of thumbnail generation in the official wiki of paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/wiki/Thumbnail-Generation).
Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988527/how-can-i-reduce-the-quality-of-an-uploading-image-using-paperclip) could be useful.

Comment: Hello thanks for the answer but yeah this, I know :D. I know how to change the quality of the thumb or medium or large version of the upload, but I want to lower the quality of the original. I can't find a way to do that, I don't want to keep the original full HD picture.

Comment: Did you take a look at the [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988527/how-can-i-reduce-the-quality-of-an-uploading-image-using-paperclip) I shared above?

Comment: You said your original photo was huge, maybe you could go into something like [this question on improving image compression with paperclip and imagemagick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30263290/how-do-i-improve-rails-paperclip-image-compression-inside-or-imagemagick-rma).
Or get your hands dirty with [the usage of quality options in imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#quality).